# Making interfaces in A-frame

Tags: javascript, augmented-reality, aframe

I just started with Javascript 3 days ago. The thing is I have to develop an AR app hosted in web, so I went for A-frame. So far so good. Problem is our client wants to add some complex UI, similar to a classic 2D UI from a
videogame.

So, what should I do about it? I tried React but I have read in forums React+A-Frame is a bad idea, and it doesn't render at all. What do you think is the best approach?

Currently, I am trying to hard code it, although I don't have enough understanding of JavaScript to even know if that's a good idea.

There is a nasty deadline in 2 months, in which I guess I'll have to learn JS and develop this thing.

I tried React + A-Frame, but didn't made it to work. I just want to make an interface for a game in A-Frame

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You say react + aframe didn't work. What was the issue? As long as the scene is in a separate component and you don't re-render it you shouldnt fall into any traps

Comment: Well, I added the <a-scene> that I got to work in a simple previous html and it did not render. 

Then, I added the one scene in this example [link](https://www.newline.co/fullstack-react/articles/react-and-webvr-using-aframe/) , and yes, it rendered. But, I need to use device's camera, so I changed it to do so, but it did not come to render it. 

The code I changed is this:
`<a-scene id="mainscene" embedded arjs='sourceType: webcam;' renderer='antialias: true; alpha: true; precision: medium;'>`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML superimposed on the screen, as an overlay and then wire in some event listeners to dispatch to your a-frame scene.

Drop in your a-frame markup, and then separately add a `<div id="ui"></div>` which fills all the screen on top of the 3d/ar canvas, then you can add normal HTML such as buttons, text, etc.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/luigimannoni/webxr-earthday) you can take inspiration from just to have a visual idea of how it works but please do not use it as a working base as it is not a-frame, it's quite outdated now, it's a lousy integration between react and threejs well before react-three-fiber was even a thing and definitely not friendly for someone starting to code with javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Still, I think I am gonna make the functionalities myself, since it is not much work and they aren't that many.